# What does "Final MON" mean in MLB Sunday games results?

Tags: terminology, major-leagues

I've seen F/10 MON and F/11 MON and Final MON written after game results in the banner across the bottom of the TV, in WMBA, MLB and MLS, What does MON mean?

Google is giving me nothing.

UPDATE:
Typical result reads: "REDS 4, METS 6, F/11 MON." I have found F/11 means 11 rounds, and "FINAL MON" means the usual 9 rounds. However I've seen FINAL MON behind soccer results, so who knows what MON means. I'll try to take a screen shot.

UPDATE2:
There is no MLB on Mondays - Ever.
However, the results for MLB weekdays show "FINAL", and (I've just found out) "FINAL MON" Is only shown on Sunday games.
Perhaps it means final game up until monday (but not on monday) - How WEIRD.

I'll try to take a screenshot on Sunday.

UPDATE 3:
I was misled, our network wont show MLB on Mondays, certainly there is baseball on Mondays, my apologies. I have now seen "FINAL MON" on Wednesdays and Sundays.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or a link using that language?  It might mean Monday or Montreal, but neither seems a perfect fit for your description.

Comment: No baseball on mondays, and not montreal, a typical result might be "REDS 4, METS 6, F/11 MON." I have found F/11 means 11 rounds, and "FINAL MON" means the usual 9?

Comment: Surely it wouldn't be FINAL MON as in french for END ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a reference or a screenshot?

F/10 or F/11 is only commonly used for baseball (MLB) scores.  In that case it indicates the game is over (game is "F"inal), and that rather than the regulation 9 innings, additional innings were played (10 or 11).  I can't think of any reason you would see this terminology with WNBA or MLS scores.  Overtime for those games are indicated differently.

For MLS (or NHL or CFL), "MON" is most likely the abbreviation for Montreal, which has a team in those leagues.

For WNBA or MLB, the only thing I can see with that is someone reporting that the score is from a game played on Monday.  But the provider might be trying to say something else that I'm missing.  An image could clear it up.

Comment: There is no MLB on Monday, ever. In fact FINAL MON is only shown on Sunday games. As if indicating the end of the baseball week

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without a screenshot in question, but likely refers to Monday. As in F/10 MON, would mean the baseball game final score in ten innings is for Monday's game. This might appear Tuesday afternoon, when it's possible for a game to have started, but they are still showing yesterday's results. You might also see this in the playoffs, when they want to show how the series is going so far and are noting that the previous game was on Monday.

Comment: There is no MLB on Monday, ever. In fact FINAL MON is only shown on Sunday games. As if indicating the end of the baseball week.

Comment: Are you getting scores for the entire week then? Does WED or FRI show up? This must be something local to your broadcast in that case and not US TV standard.

Answer (score -1):

There are MLB games on Monday: http://m.mlb.com/schedule/2018/08/13/

I always thought F/MON or the equivalent meant the game started on Sunday, but ended after midnight, meaning the game ended on Monday. That would explain why "FINAL MON" is only shown on Sunday games.